# Design of variable split rail power supply

Tags: power-supply, piezo, transducer, virtual-ground

I'm attempting to drive an array of piezo transducers and am struggling to find a good design capable of driving from around +-5V to +-30V at about 2A for my testing. There are about 12 sets of transducers that will need to operate independently and thus require their own driving circuitry. I am planning to use half H-bridges for this. Something like this image:

[image]

I've got access to a 0-30V, 10A supply, but most of the circuits I've come across for split rail designs are a bit underpowered and intended for fixed voltages such as this one:

[image: Virtual ground circuit]

I also looked at using something like an LM1370 (500kHz High Efficiency
6A Switching Regulator), but it seems as though it may underpowered too.

I apologise if this question is a bit open-ended, but if anyone has any advice on an reasonable solution for this, I'd be very grateful.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Why do you need a dual-voltage supply when you're using H-bridges? H-bridges generally use a positive supply only and generate AC by alternately switching the devices terminals to V+ and 0 V.

Comment: I was planning to use a _half_ H-bridge design which uses the dual rails, to save on component numbers if I implement a full H-bridge. I added an image to clarify.

Comment: That sound like a lot of current.  You could look into various smps/ DC-DC converters.  Or maybe just buy another 0-30 V power supply.

Comment: Yes, I'll be looking at various transducers designs for this research. There will around 120 transducers, so I am just over engineering the supply to give me more flexibility. I did consider  getting another 0-30V supply.

Comment: Just another idea to think about. Use a half-bridge, set to fixed 50% duty cycle, put a LC filter on the output. It is basically a synchronous buck. Obviously, the half-bridge output components have to be sized to your power and ripple requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm attempting to drive an array of piezo transducers and am
>   struggling to find a good design capable of driving from around +-5V
>   to +-30V at about 2A for my testing.

Piezo's are capacitive and don't care if there is DC content across their terminals or not. Just design a single-sided H bridge and if you are really worried then use a capacitor in series with your piezo, just like a push pull audio amp does with a ground referenced speaker and a single-sided supply: -

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the "flavor" of the OP's piezo, but I use some that are DC devices.  (position control)

Comment: @GeorgeHerold do you have a link - it would be useful to me.

Comment: Thanks for the replies gentlemen. Due to my application, I'm interested in the dilatation part of the waveform, which is why I was considering split rail. I'll look further into using a push-pull design with the series capacitor.

Comment: @Andyaka http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=8040 http://www.thorlabs.de/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=61 Well here are a few, we use something like the second link, but buy from a distributor (not Thor labs.)  These are ~100V and move a few microns.  I can look up the part number and distributor if that is what you might be looking for,

Comment: @Cotlone, I should add that these piezo actuators are polarized... they do not like too big a reverse voltage.

Comment: @GeorgeHerold if the OP is using a polarized one then taking the voltage too negative could be very problematic!

Comment: @GeorgeHerold thanks for the link. At this stage though, we probably aren't looking at polarised actuators. The piezos will be used for US generation.

Comment: @Andyaka I appreciate the DC filtration of the load, thanks for the explanation. I just had a thought though, if I use a PWM signal to modulate power to the transducers, is this likely to cause a baseline shift resulting in an unbalanced voltage swing? Am I right in thinking that regardless of whether I use bipolar power rails, this effect would still occur?

Comment: I'm unsure what you mean by a baseline shift and unbalanced voltage swing.

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong here, but does not a series capacitor prevent transmission of DC component by essentially, causing zero net charge transfer between point and negative swings, such as that seen is this image: 

http://www.dnp.fmph.uniba.sk/~kollar/je_w/image464.gif

If this is correct, a sequence of unipolar pulses has a DC base line component that would depend on duty factor. 

I imagine that, with reference to an unbiased piezo device, the amount of strain induced in either direction would be effected by the applied voltage in that direction.

Comment: If you are using a basic piezo device then it has series capacitance and this will do exactly the same as an external capacitor. So, with a series of unipolar pulses there will be a an average dc offset across that capacitor, yes. Will it affect what you want to do - it might if you have a piezo transducer that elongates an amount and stays elongated while DC is applied. I'm not sure that this happens in a piezo - isn't movement due to the differential of voltage applied i.e. if you compressed a piezo it would generate volts but then that voltage would fall to zero.

Comment: @Andyaka Thanks for your reply and sorry about my delay! Ok, I'm not sure whether that happens either, I actually thought it was a linear effect due to the electric field. But I think that running a unipolar configuration will not be an issue unless I get into non-linear response regions of the piezo (which I'm not likely to). 

As a related point, do you think there are any issues in having a common ground across all of these bridges which will be running out of phase (independently)?

Comment: I don't see that being a problem.